# RestKit: mapping class is nil in Swift

Tags: swift, restkit

I'm a newbie in Swift and RestKit, and I'm trying to make a simple sample to run, here's my mapping code:

```
var mapping = RKObjectMapper(forClass: User.self)
println(mapping.objectClass)
mapping.addAttibuteMappingsFromArray(["id", "email"])
```

when running the code, debugger says `NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil`. And the 2nd line prints `'nil'`. I suspect I didn't init the mapper object properly, but what is the correct way? Google tells me almost nothing. Appreciate your help!

**edit:**

User class declaration:

```
class User {
    var id: Int?
    var email: String

    init(id: Int?, email: String!) {
        self.id = id
        self.email = email
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

Seems like the class should be a sub-class of NSObject. To solve the problem, change class declaration to `class User: NSObject`.

Comment: what is the code of "User" initialization ?

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and mark it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the class should be a sub-class of NSObject. To solve the problem, change class declaration to `class User: NSObject`.